# How can I debug Silverlight 5 applications in Visual Studio 2012 after installing Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, silverlight-5.0, internet-explorer-10

I can no longer debug my Silverlight application in Visual Studio after updating to Internet Explorer 10. I made no other changes to my system and it was working fine with Internet Explorer 9 just before the update to IE10. When I hit F5 in Visual Studio, IE10 is fired up and the Silverlight application runs in the browser, but breakpoints are not hit in Silverlight code. If I hit shift+F5 (stop debugging), the browser remains open (this used to shut it down).  Alternatively, if I close the browser while debugging, it doesn't stop debugging in Visual Studio (which it always did before).  I'm running Win7 64.

This problem has also been reproduced in Visual Studio 2010 and Silverlight 4.

Comment: I have since switched to FireFox for debugging (which works fine), but would like to figure out why it doesn't work with IE10.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do fix Visual Studio 2012 after installing IE10 on Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480436/how-do-fix-visual-studio-2012-after-installing-ie10-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2012 and Silverlight 5. The symptoms that I was getting included the following.

1. Multiple browser instances would be opened when I started the application in debug mode within Visual Studio.
2. I sometimes got an error in the browser saying that the application could not be loaded.
3. Visual Studio would automatically detach from the browser and drop out of debug mode.
4. Turning off the Silverlight debugger (see the Web tab in the properties dialog for the web project) seemed to result in less of the other problems. This did however mean that I could not debug Silverlight code.

To resolve these issues, I right clicked on an aspx file in the solution explorer and selected 'Browse With...' to open the following dialog.

[image: Browse With Dialog]

Note that there are two entries for 'Internet Explorer'.

I removed both (I set Firefox as the default temporarily to do so), cancelled out of the dialog and then reopened it. At this point, a new entry for 'Internet Explorer' had been added back in automatically. I made this the default and then had no further issues.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same with VS2012..
Looks like Visual studio got confused which IE to use - somehow in system I hade two instances of IE as target browser (In VS2012  window called "Browse With..")
I removed all IE's from VS targets and restarted VS. Then only one instance of IE appeared after and debugger attaches normally.

Comment: I did that and now it's OK.  I right-clicked the default.aspx host page and when selected "Browse With..." and removed IE.  I then re-added it and now the debugger attaches.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after opening a Silverlight-based application in two instances of IE10 at the same time.  I could not debug.  After which, I had switched between Chrome and IE10 in order to try and solve the problem.  I could debug in Chrome but not IE10. But Chrome was cumbersome to run for debugging purposes.

Ultimately, I had to remove all the temporary files associated with VS builds in a three places:

```
C:\Users\brchase\AppData\Local
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

As well, I had to do a complete clean on the project and shut down IISExpress.

Also, I did a `Tools /Delete Browsing History in IE10`.

The above worked and I could debug again in IE10 -- even with multiple instances running.

Answer (score 0):

Using Winserver 2008R2, VS2012 or VS2010. Latest version of FireFox does not hit SilverLight breakpoints. Tim Heurs solution at http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/16/enable-silverlight-debugging-in-firefox-visual-studio.aspx does not apply as the required line is not in the FireFox config. My fix was to go back to IE9 (My IE10 was broken so I can't say for sure IE10 doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Tried all of these suggestions.

Finally had to remove and re-install VS 2012 (which isn't straight forward anymore because after Oct 2013 some of the certificates had expired).  Yay Microsoft!

So after re-installing I still had to go into the "Browse To" and switch it from IE to another choice then back to IE and it magically works now..

I think it was because Internet Explorer updated itself and left VS confused..