# how to fix Visual Studio 2012 after installing IE10 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012, internet-explorer-10

I recently upgraded my machine to **Internet Explorer 10**. I use **Visual Studio 2012** (VS2012) under Windows 7. Since I upgraded to IE10, VS2012 **does not automatically attach** to the `iexplorer.exe` process anymore. And I have 2 entries in the drop down.

[image: duplicate Internet Explorer entries]

**Any idea what I should do?**

(Yes, I should be upgrading to Win8 and a clean install in the coming months...)

Comment: in the drop down-menu, don't you have a "choose browser"-button?

Comment: @JanHommes, yes, but as you can see on the screenshot, I have 2 IE entries... Yes, I will likely delete one of them, but I was just wondering if anybody else had this issue and if there was a more elegant way to fix this.

Comment: sorry, can't see the images on work. I'am using Win 8 and didn't need to update to ie 10. But maybe you have a 32 bit and a 64 bit version of IE installed?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I am not sure if you already found a solution on this but if you select any other browser, in your case select Google Chrome. Then, run your solution, then stop. Change back to Internet Explorer and voila... the other IE entry will be removed and fixes the debugger attach issue. Try it, it worked for me.

Comment: Works for IE 11 as well.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by opening the "Browse with..."-Dialog and removing one of the two "Internet Explorer" entries.

Answer (score 2):

I had two entries of IE on my VS 2012

1. Remove one entry of Internet Explorer from 'Browse With' option.
2. Now browse with any other browser - say Google Chrome
3. Stop. Now second entry of IE is removed from debug options.
4. Now browse with Internet Explorer.

It works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read previous answers before posting. pinoy_ISF already answered pretty much the same thing you just posed.