# Using VS 2012 with IE 10 and Win 7, Debugging won't end when Browser closed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, internet-explorer-10

I have a .net app in VS 2012.  I recently upgraded to IE10 on Win 7.  When I used IE9, and closed the browser window during a debugging session, the debugging session ended as well.  Now it won't and I have to end it manually.  Vice versa, if I end the debugging session with a terminate all, the browser window won't close.

Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: This is not a really an issue. You can always do it manually.

Comment: Are you encountering a similar issue as listed in this post - where there are two IE entries? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480436/how-to-fix-visual-studio-2012-after-installing-ie10-on-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

Try to Run the app/project with a different browser, close it and run it again with Internet Explorer.

This is actually and issue related to a bug in Visual Studio, If you have got a breakpoint it will not be hit because the VS and IE are not linked/connected/communicating.