# How to attach Visual Studio to Internet Explorer automatically

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and IE11. When I press F5, it opens the web page but it does not attach to the IE automatically. I have to do it every time manually through Debug > Attach to Process > choose iexplore.exe. Is there any way to do this automatically? This problem happens when I update the IE from IE9 to IE11. I tried resetting the VS environment but it also does not work.

Comment: try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951124/visual-studio-auto-attach-to-a-process-when-the-process-is-spawned

Comment: also try this solution - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/261638/Automate-the-attach-to-process

Comment: are you using the Metro IE 11 or the desktop IE 11?

Comment: @KCdod Thanks for the answer, but I don't want to do this programatically. Previously when I used IE9, it attached automatically. Only then when I update to IE11 this stops working. So I would love to see a solution without changing the code.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling visual studio?

Comment: @Mark I did not try reinstalling the VS, but it will be great if I can just change some setting in the VS rather than reinstalling.

Comment: try - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480436/how-to-fix-visual-studio-2012-after-installing-ie10-on-windows-7

Comment: @KCdod It also does not work. Strangely, it also gives me "there are no more files" when starting the project.

Comment: is your VS 2012 updated :) ?

Comment: @KCdod I am using VS 2012 Update 4. It should be the latest update already.

Comment: seems you will need some workaround rather than a solution :)

Comment: Haha anything that can make this work, I'll be happy :) (Except reinstalling everything :p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I finally resolve this issue. This issue is caused by IE11 running on 64-bit mode.
So I have to force IE to run in 32-bit mode by adding the registry key as mentioned in this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/561036/unable-to-open-ie-10-in-32-bit-mode). Then after that, I need to remove the "Internet Explorer" entry as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480436/how-to-fix-visual-studio-2012-after-installing-ie10-on-windows-7).