# ChildWindow Breakpoints

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0, breakpoints, childwindow

I have a project in Silverlight with a ChildWindow, this ChildWindow has various breakpoints, but When I run my application, the code does not stop for that lines.

Can someone help me? I don't see which is the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to attache the debugger to the instance running your silverlight application. If it is the browser, you need to attach to it.

Might be also the same issue as discussed over here: [How can I debug Silverlight 5 applications in Visual Studio 2012 after installing Internet Explorer 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188151/how-can-i-debug-silverlight-5-applications-in-visual-studio-2012-after-installin)

Comment: The problem not is resolved yet, I tried with this solution but I have the same problem.